# Show that $\displaystyle{\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}} \dfrac{e^\frac{-1}{x}-1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}dx$ converges

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have the following integral

$\displaystyle{\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}} \dfrac{e^\frac{-1}{x}-1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}dx$

First I split it into

$\displaystyle{\int \limits_{0}^{1}} \dfrac{e^\frac{-1}{x}-1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}dx 
\;+\; 
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{1}^{\infty}} \dfrac{e^\frac{-1}{x}-1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}dx$

And I was able to show that $\displaystyle{\int \limits_{0}^{1}} \dfrac{e^\frac{-1}{x}-1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}dx < \infty$. Indeed, $e^{\frac{-1}{x}}$ is bounded in $[0,1$] by some $K$, therefore

$\displaystyle{\int \limits_{0}^{1}} | \dfrac{e^\frac{-1}{x}-1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}} | dx 
\leq 
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{0}^{1}} \dfrac{K}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}} < \infty$

However, I got stuck on the second integral $\displaystyle{\int \limits_{1}^{\infty}} \dfrac{e^\frac{-1}{x}-1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}dx$. I would like to show that it is convergent too. I tried substituting $t = \dfrac{1}{x}$, but it did not seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Making the substitution $t=\frac{1}{x}$ and integrating by part
$$\int _0^\infty \dfrac{e^\frac{-1}{x}-1}{x^\frac{2}{3}}dx=\int _0^\infty (e^{-t}-1)t^{-\frac{4}{3}}dt=-3\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{-\frac{1}{3}}dt=-3\Gamma\Big(\frac{2}{3}\Big)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $e^{-s}-1=-(1-e^{-s})$  and $0 \leq 1-e^{-s} \leq s$ for $s \geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks. And when combining it with @xzm answer we get the final result!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\int_1^\infty\left| \frac{e^{-\frac1x} - 1}{x^{\frac23}} \right|dx \le \int \left| \frac{1/x}{x^{\frac23}}\right| dx
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ e^{-\frac{1}{x}} = 1 - \frac{1}{x} + o(\frac{1}{x})(x \to +\infty) $$

Hence $$ \dfrac{e^\frac{-1}{x}-1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}} = \frac{-\frac{1}{x}+ o(\frac{1}{x})}{x^\frac{2}{3}} \sim -\frac{1}{x^\frac{5}{3}} $$

And $ -\frac{1}{x^\frac{5}{3}} $ is integrable at infinity